# Python pyqt5 not executing SQL statement

Tags: python, sql, pyqt5

I'm trying to execute a SQL statement in Python/pyqt5, but every time I run this code

```
self.view.resizeColumnToContents()
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: resizeColumnToContents(self, int): not enough arguments

I've been trying to use different SQL statements, but no success

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QLabel, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem

class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle(" work overflow")
        self.resize(1000, 500)
        #view setup
        self.view = QTableWidget()
        #2 kolumny
        self.view.setColumnCount(2)
        self.view.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["EWR", "Description", " id "])
        query = QSqlQuery("SELECT * from _tbl_BuildPhases")
        while query.next():
            rows = self.view.rowCount()
            self.view.setRowCount(rows+1)
            self.view.setItem(rows, 0, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(0)))
            #self.view.setItem(rows, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(1))))
            self.view.setItem(rows, 1, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1)))

        self.view.resizeColumnToContents()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)



#Creating connection with DB
def createConnection():
    con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    con.setDatabaseName("xyz")
    con.setUserName("sa")
    con.setPassword("xyz")

    if not con.open():
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "work overflow- Error",
                             "DataBase Error: %s" % con.lastError().databaseText())
        return False
    return True


# create App
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#App window
if not createConnection():
    sys.exit(1)

win = mainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That error message has **absolutely nothing** to do with SQL or your data operation ....

Comment: `resizeColumnToContents` takes an argument, which column to resize. Have a look at the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#resizeColumnToContents)

Comment: Ok, passing argument into  **resizeColumnToContents** helped but data from sql is missing

Comment: @Spinny Why do you think the data is "missing"? Have you actually checked that the sql statement is correct, and, if so, how?

Comment: @ekhumoro Because in mainWindow where i display ewr - description-id  there is no data only column names. Sql statment is correct base on data from DB - where i have 26 records

Comment: @Spinny Use the fullpath of the .db since SQLITE has a special case is that if the path does not exist then it will create it so theoretically db.open will never be false

Comment: I've tried this also i've added host name but still no success. I have also made simple code with same db and with `print(query.exec("SELECT * from [xyz].[dbo].[_tbl_BuildPhases]"))` in return i have false. Any ideas mb there is problem with db not with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QLabel, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem


class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("ProtoLab work overflow")
        self.resize(1000, 500)
        #view setup
        self.view = QTableWidget()
        #2 kolumny
        self.view.setColumnCount(3)
        self.view.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["EWR", "Description", " x "])
        query = QSqlQuery("SELECT * from [EWR_ProtoLab].[dbo].[_tbl_BuildPhases]")
        while query.next():
            rows = self.view.rowCount()
            self.view.setRowCount(rows+1)
            self.view.setItem(rows, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(0))))
            self.view.setItem(rows, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(1))))
            self.view.setItem(rows, 2, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(2)))

        #self.view.resizeColumnToContents(1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)



#Creating connection with DB
def createConnection():
 
    constring = ('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};''SERVER=xyz;DATABASE=xxx;UID=sa;PWD=xyz')
    con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC")

    con.setDatabaseName(constring)

    if not con.open():
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "ProtoLAB work overflow- Error",
                             "DataBase Error: %s" % con.lastError().databaseText())
        return False
    return True


# create App
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#App window
if not createConnection():
    sys.exit(1)

win = mainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```